# Fishers method to combine pvalues in Java

Tags: java, p-value

I have two genes with their Pvalues and I have to implement Fisher method on this using JAVA (its requirement). I performed expensive RnD but I couldn't find any help. 
There is also build-in fisher method implementation in R which is as follow.

```
function (p) 
{
 keep <- (p > 0) & (p <= 1)
 lnp <- log(p[keep])
 chisq <- (-2) * sum(lnp)
 df <- 2 * length(lnp)
 if (sum(1L * keep) < 2) 
     stop("Must have at least two valid p values")
 if (length(lnp) != length(p)) {
     warning("Some studies omitted")
 }
 res <- list(chisq = chisq, df = df, p = pchisq(chisq, df, 
    lower.tail = FALSE), validp = p[keep])
 class(res) <- c("sumlog", "metap")
 res
}
```

Can anyone help me in understanding this code or if possible, share the Fisher method implementation in java?.

Comment: Looks like someone has already done it for you  >http://www.users.zetnet.co.uk/hopwood/tools/StatTests.java

Comment: Thanks DejaVu. But in link, its using 4 p values and playing around with that in formula. But I want to check this between 2 pavlues.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can curtail the number of p values it looks at. But I am not a stat programmer.